# Chrome - Box shadow on :active causes bottom padding to disappear

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I suppose the best way to show this is in an example: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4GfWY/4/)

Notice that the container (`.overlay_inner`) with the black border has padding on all sides. If you click on the button in the top right labeled "select" the container's bottom padding disappears!

This strange behavior only occurs for me in Chrome (version 13). I don't see it in IE or Firefox.

I've sort of narrowed the problem down to this block of CSS:

```
input[type=button]:active {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea, #e2e2e2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #aaa;
}
```

Relevant part is the `box-shadow`. When I remove that bit of CSS, the problem doesn't occur. Doesn't make sense to me, though. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** Potential work-around found. I removed the container's bottom padding and added a placeholder `div` at the bottom with a height equal to the padding amount removed.

Example: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4GfWY/5/)

Feels really hackish which makes me uncomfortable since I thought I left that behind when I stopped writing for IE, but oh well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I managed to minify the test case to this: http://jsfiddle.net/4GfWY/8/ and I found that the requirements for this bug to occur are:

1. You must have a block with

   ```
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;/* Or on any other block in this but over absolute one */
   padding-bottom: 100px;/* Any bottom padding */
   ```
2. Some content that would cause a vertical scrollbar.
3. An inner block with `position: absolute`.
4. And if you'd then change `box-shadow` for this inner block, the bug occurs.

So, there can be a lot of workarounds, the best I think is: http://jsfiddle.net/4GfWY/9/

There I replaced the `position: absolute` to `float: right` (and made some other corresponding changes ), so:

1. One of the requirments for bug is gone, and the bug itself is gone.
2. If you'd have a lot of text in title, you could make it wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4GfWY/10/ (I replaced there `height` to `min-height`), so the button wouldn't overlay the title's text.